# Why is the function $|x-1|\sqrt{x}$ not continuous at point $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

The function $|x-1|\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on the interval $(0, \infty)$, but I don't understand why isn't it continuous at $0$. Could somebody tell me, please?

Comment: No.  Because it is.  Why did you think it wasn't.

Comment: Maybe confused with the question :Differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: You have to determine the intervals of continuity and differentiability. The answer was given (by the teacher) for both questions, and it's $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: she must've been mistaken then

Comment: The left hand limit doesn't exist at $0.$  However, is it necessary for the left hand limit to exist for a function to be continuous?  And the answer is, in fact, no, it doesn't.  If the area to the left of 0 is not in the domain, the neighborhood around $0$ can be entirely to the right of $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** continuous at $0$ (as a function on $[0,\infty)$).